# How to send a customer comment with shipping method in magento checkout?

Tags: magento-1.7

I need to send a customer comment, with selected magento shipping method. How can I do that.

I made a module to override `available.phtml` file, where shipping methods are listed out. I can put a textbox there too. But how can I took its value along with the shipping description? Where should I make changes.

Any help will be appreciated. I am a newbie to Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to your goal would be:

- create a extension base
- create a setup script that adds comment variable to shipping object , to quote or to order
- create a template and append this to proper place with xml layout rules
- create a event observer and observe the shipping method save or checkout save event (depends where you reference your template)
- and in this observer check if your extension is active and your from field has the value and save or set it to appropriate object

Answer (score 0):

This may help : https://github.com/drewhunter/ShipNote

> This extension provides a way for customers to notify store owners of
>   any special shipping requirements during the checkout process on both
>   front and back end orders.

Since you want to learn magento (?) I would suggest you have a look at the code, and learn from it, as it does what you need to do :)

ps: I have not used this extension myself.